# Agora.io token issue Android

Tags: android, agora.io

We are generating agora token from token server provided by agora but the token expires immmediately after the generation it throws DYNAMIC-KEY-EXPIRY with error code 109 and i have tried using onRequestToken() call back method provided in SDK below is the code snippet

```
override fun onRequestToken() {
            //this will be called when the token expires
            //so generate new token and renew the existing token
            runOnUiThread {
                regenerateToken()
            }
        }
```

and getting another token from server and renewing the token using mRtcEngine.renewToken(token)
we have contacted agora team regarding this but unable to find the issue the token generated works sometimes,we have two account one is test account and other is main account when we use the one credentials it works for a day or so and after we need to change the credentials for every 2 days
and the new generated token is expiring just after the generation
So if any one faced the same issue and any help regarding this is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the token, you can set the token expiration time in the request parameter. Here is a guide for token generation. https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/token_server?platform=Android

If you have set the expiration time but still having the issue, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Yang we have solved the issue it is causing because of the timezone difference since the servers of agora are in USA we need to set the exipration accordingly

Answer (score 0):

We are generating the token using agora token server and the time expiration is 3600

```
const { RtcTokenBuilder, RtmTokenBuilder, RtcRole, RtmRole } = require('agora-access-token');
```

const role = RtcRole.PUBLISHER;

const expirationTimeInSeconds = 3600

const currentTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)

const privilegeExpiredTs = currentTimestamp + expirationTimeInSeconds

const generateAuthTokenToInititateCall = async (channel, cb) => {

```
const token = RtcTokenBuilder.buildTokenWithUid(appID, appCertificate, channel, 0, role, privilegeExpiredTs);

cb({ "token": token, "channel": channel })
```

}

this is the node js code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Is anyone able to resolve this? This is occurring despite setting the expiration to 3600 seconds (1 hour from current time).

Comment: Hi my3vshenoy we have solved the issue it is causing because of the timezone difference since the servers of agora are in USA we need to set the exipration accordingly

Answer (score 0):

let me make this token generation for you very simple and also the later process.

*firstly how to generate token?

you need a backend server which provides you with token when you provide the server a channel name. no where you will be told that this backend server is not necessary. rather you can copy - paste the token generation code directly into the app in a form of directory.

*where is this token generation code?

https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/tree/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/java/src
this code is available for flutter also research a little bit.

*how to generate token using it?

once you have the all java files in your project you can use them to generate the token. here you can see a variable expirationTimeInSeconds, that will be the total time you want token to be active. rest all work leave it to the code it will do it for you.

```
package io.agora.sample;

import io.agora.media.RtcTokenBuilder;
import io.agora.media.RtcTokenBuilder.Role;

public class RtcTokenBuilderSample {
    static String appId = "970CA35de60c44645bbae8a215061b33";
    static String appCertificate = "5CFd2fd1755d40ecb72977518be15d3b";
    static String channelName = "7d72365eb983485397e3e3f9d460bdda";
    static String userAccount = "2082341273";
    static int uid = 2082341273;
    static int expirationTimeInSeconds = 3600; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RtcTokenBuilder token = new RtcTokenBuilder();
        int timestamp = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + expirationTimeInSeconds);
        String result = token.buildTokenWithUserAccount(appId, appCertificate,  
                 channelName, userAccount, Role.Role_Publisher, timestamp);
        System.out.println(result);
        
        result = token.buildTokenWithUid(appId, appCertificate,  
             channelName, uid, Role.Role_Publisher, timestamp);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

result here is the generated token which is valid for 3600 seconds, that is 1hour.